# Safer way to connect to Remote Database in applications

Tags: c#, php, android, mysql, xamarin

Let's say I'm making an Xamarin.android (let's take it as any platform/framework). So, I have to use remote database for store and retrieve information.

I've been making PHP based APIs on my server that interact with database. I make my application hit up those API endpoints with the data and those APIs update the information in the database.

So, I was wondering that if I make my application directly connect to the remote MySQL, it'll be a bit faster than hitting up APIs.

Which way would be safer? I don't want anyone to be able to intercept the data or connection details to DB for obvious reasons. What would be the safest way? Or is there any other way to get this job done?

Comment: Short answer: API is safer assuming the API doesn't have SQL injections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about safer for now; A back-end layer (the API server in your case) will make your system more decoupled, and it is the least thing to do. suppose you suddenly decided to use another type of database, lets say PostgreSQL instead of MYSQL, you will need probably to use different format for connection strings, are you willing to update all your clients android apps with new database connection string each time?  this will take time and cost and will make your application difficult to maintain, and break it at users end.

And yes, it is safer to use APIs (in your case); It is much easier to reverse engineer a client application such as android app than hacking a well secured and designed server. as you said in your question, knowing too much makes your database vulnerable to multiple types of attacks. therefore, it is much safer to encapsulate your database with an API.

However, it is not enough to use an API to make your system safer; you should also follow best practices. for example; use a HTTPS, use authentication techniques (passwords, Oauth2), use authorization, etc...

Still, i am not saying, it is not possible to use your database directly without API, you can secure your database with different techniques, it is possible but **NOT** recommended at all.

Comment: Yes OAuth 2.0 token propagation from the client to the DB through the API is the way.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking the same. Was looking for some faster performance overall. But, Data Security is much more important. Thank you for your views and suggestions :)